# After the Big Bang Planck time

Tags: time, big-bang

What happened before the Planck time in the big bang? I have seen a timeline for after the big bang but there is no description of what happened before the Planck time.

Comment: No one knows. Whatever was happening, quantum gravity was definitely involved. None of the accepted physical theories can really make predictions that early on.

Comment: You didn't exist before you were born, why does it surprise you that the universe did not exist before it was born? In the geometry of our spacetime, there is no direction to "before" the Big Bang the same way as in the geometry of a globe there is no direction "farther to the North" at the North Pole. Everything starts at $Time = 1$ in Plank units and goes forward as $2$, $3$, $4$, etc., as frames of a motion picture. There are no frames before the first frame.

Comment: I am not talking about before the big bang, i am talking about what happened before the plank time, e.g. 10^-44 seconds in.